# Disable the "Dwell" menubar entry

Tags: menu-bar

I accidentally enabled the Dwell menubar option with Onyx and can't figure out how to disable it. The "Show dwell actions in menu bar" option is already unchecked under *System Preferences->Accessibility->Accessibility Keyboard->Options->Dwell*.

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: Yes, many times.